# Non-unique foreign key in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have a database design question, to which either of the following two would be help I would appreciate:

1) Explanation why what I'm doing is a bad design decision, and how to design it better

2) Example how to actually implement the desired design in PostgreSQL

In short, what I'm doing is designing a tree-structure where each node should have a revision history like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Nodes
(
  nid BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  node_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  parent_nodeid BIGINT,
  revision_id INTEGER NOT NULL,

  .. additional columns with info about this node ..
)
```

The idea is the following; I might have a structure like:

```
root node
    child node 1
    child node 2
```

When a user edits the information in the "root node"; instead of just replacing the values in the existing log, I want to keep a log of the previous values so I instead create a new "revision" of the row - so the user sometime far in the future can do an "undo" and return to the previous configuration of the node.

What I want to achieve, is that child nodes automatically refer to the new parent node without having to update `parent_nodeid` of the children as the new revision of the root node should not change the hierarchy of the node tree.

I understand that I cannot add a foreign key from `Nodes.parent_nodeid` to `Nodes.node_id` as PostgreSQL requires foreign keys to reference columns with a unique value - but I'm kind of lost on how to add some kind of constraint that at least guarantees that `Nodes.parent_nodeid` references an existing `Nodes.node_id` value even though it won't be unique.

Any help/ideas would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a tree structure, as you always have only one level of dependency. Normalized database design:

```
create table nodes (
    node_id bigserial primary key,
    description text
)

create table revisions (
    revision_id bigserial primary key,
    node_id bigint references nodes,
    description text
);
```

You need a trigger on `nodes` which duplicates old row to `descriptions` on `insert` or `update` and copies a row from `revisions` instead of `delete`, implementing `undo`.

It is also not clear why to keep two nodes identifiers `nid` and `node_id`? This seems redundant.

Comment: Thank you! I think I might have left out some details in my initial question: 

- The nodes themselves describe a tree; the purpose of this design is to serve as the storage model of a typical composite-leaf style GUI editor of documents

- An example of a typical user edit action that should be versioned could be "move child node N into a new parent"; I then want to create a new revision of the given child node where the parameter that has changed is the parent node id, but the child node itself could still have other children that should after the change refer to the new revision of it

Comment: However, I do see now your point on how I should normalize this which I think will solve my problem. Thank you!